# MySql store strings in variables and concatenate them to return them to the terminal

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say that I have:

```
SET @fname := "James", @mname := "Robert", @lname := "Maxon";
```

How would I set a variable that would contain the concatenated result of the above variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SET @concatenated = CONCAT(@fname, @mname, @mname)
```

or if you want to separate the names with a space:

```
SET @concatenated = CONCAT_WS(' ', @fname, @mname, @mname)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do:

```
set @name := concat(@fname, @mname, @lname);
```

Although you might want to include spaces in between, either explicitly or using `ws_concat()`.

```
set @name := ws_concat(' ', @fname, @mname, @lname);
```